# Marcador en el mapa, usando react js

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un proyecto con el mapa de google maps y no se como ni encuentro una pagina que me diga como añadir un marcador en el mapa en donde sea que el usuario clickee, la documentacion oficial esta en typescript y yo no se typescript, por ende no puedo intentar cambiarlo a javascript, pego el codigo que tengo hasta ahora, si alguien tiene una sugerencia sobre ese codigo bienvenida es.

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const SimpleMap = () => {
    
    return (
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_MAPS_API_KEY }}
          defaultCenter={{lat: 11.0168, lng: 76.9558}}
          defaultZoom={11}
        >
        </GoogleMapReact>

    );
}

export default SimpleMap;
```

esto lo unico que hace es mostrar el mapa, pero no añade el marcador al darle click en ningun lado, pense en usar un addeventlistener pero creo que no serviria ya que las coordenadas son cosas de la api

Answer (score 0):

Si ves la guía de [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react)

Necesitas crear un componente que haga de "marcador"

```
const Marcador = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;
```

Te dejo un ejemplo rápido que he hecho, solamente le he definido un estilos en css para que se vea. **Puedes pasarle por props las cordenadas.**

```
import React from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import './marcador.css'

const Marcador = () => <div className="marcador"></div>;

export default function SimpleMap(){
  const defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 10.99835602,
      lng: 77.01502627
    },
    zoom: 11
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "" }}
        defaultCenter={defaultProps.center}
        defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
      >
        <Marcador
          lat={59.955413}
          lng={30.337844}
          text="My Marker"
        />
      </GoogleMapReact>
    </div>
  );
}
```

marcador.css

```
.marcador {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sisi eso lo vi, el problema es como hago yo para que el usuario pueda clickear y las coordenadas se me guarden o en una variable o en un array, eso no lo vi en ninguna parte e intente hacer algo con la documentacion pero esta en tsx no en js ni en jsx y typescript no puedo usar en mi proyecto de js